# Excel VBA: Speed up my Array's Binary like addition

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, binary

In my VBA module, I have an Array of a dynamic length which can take the value 0 or 1 in each element. I need to generate all permutation combinations and then use it in some other calculations.

Example: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, etc.

Hence, I treated each element as a Bit and switched the 0s to 1s and vice-versa simulate a binary addition - 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, etc.

Below is my code. It works fine, but gets slow exponentially. I'd appreciate your inputs to help me optimise this code to run faster.

```
Dim lastPos As Long

Sub Main()
    Dim myArray(1 to 100, 1) As Long

    'something
    'something
    'something

    While Not Not myArray
        DoEvents

        'Do something with myArray

        byteAdd myArray
    Wend
End Sub

Sub byteAdd(ByRef inArray() As Long)
    Dim i As Long

    i = UBound(inArray)
    If (inArray(i, 1) = 0) Then
        inArray(i, 1) = 1
        lastPos = i
    Else
        For i = lastPos - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If (inArray(i, 1) = 0) Then
                Dim j As Long
                inArray(i, 1) = 1

                For j = i + 1 To UBound(inArray)
                    inArray(j, 1) = 0
                Next j

                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i

        Erase inArray
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried some other techniques...
1) I tried to increment a decimal number from 0 to the maximum decimal of 11111 (length of array) and then convert the decimal to binary. However, Excel has a 10 character limit

2) I tried to use String() and ReDim Preserve to cut off the array, or a CSV string, at the last 1, and use String() to populate remaining zeros, instead of a loop. Unfortunately, as you can see, it is a two dimensional array, and that approach didn't work

3) Using data type Byte instead of Long didn't seem to work, but prefer Long since Mathematical calculations are required off the Array.

Appreciate any solutions.

Comment: Can the array exceed 32 elements?

Comment: Yes it can. Basically, each element is a row in a range. Once of the things I do with the 1s & 0s is use it in a SUMPRODUCT WorksheetFunction. Hence there can be 100, 1000, 5000 rows, etc.

Personally, I feel, if a decimal number could have been converted to binary (at least up to 2000 bits), then using that with Split() would have been the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help. The main sub (AddOne) is agnostic between 0-based and 1-based arrays. The test sub runs in a fraction of a second:

```
Sub AddOne(binaryVector As Variant)
'adds one to an array consisting of 0s and 1s
'the vector is modified in place
'all 1's wraps around to all 0's
    Dim bit As Long, carry As Long, i As Long, ub As Long, lb As Long
    carry = 1
    lb = LBound(binaryVector)
    ub = UBound(binaryVector)
    i = ub
    Do While carry = 1 And i >= lb
        bit = (binaryVector(i) + carry) Mod 2
        binaryVector(i) = bit
        i = i - 1
        carry = IIf(bit = 0, 1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim bvect(1 To 10) As Long
    Dim bvects(1 To 1024, 1 To 10) As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To 1024 '=2^10
        For j = 1 To 10
            bvects(i, j) = bvect(j)
        Next j
        AddOne bvect
    Next i
    Range("A1:J1024").Value = bvects
End Sub
```

Comment: First, I'd need 10 rows of bit values (to use in SUMPRODUCT) as opposed to columns. Second, I will most likely need more than 32 bits (array elements) and 2^32 is a really huge number. Third, at my own test of 16 bits, your code does work faster. Finally, I will see whether I can modify this tomorrow to work with more than 32 bits.

Comment: It is trivial to transpose the data using Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(bvects). 2^32 is around 4 billion -- it isn't feasible to include it all in a single spreadsheet. If you are doing something like a brute-force knapsack problem then consider a better algorithm. For one thing -- look into Gray codes ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code ) as way to iterate through subsets in such a way that each successive subset is obtained from the previous by either adding or deleting just 1 element (see  http://stackoverflow.com/q/30970178/4996248 for some VBA code for that).

Comment: Yes, I am doing a brute force to find a target value on my sheet. Some times there are fewer than 32 bits and sometimes about 150-200. Although I do not need to show the bits on screen, just use them in calculations. Will take a look at your suggested resources as well.

Comment: I could not see any noticeable change in performance between this and my own code, but accepting this as the only and alternatively proposed solution.

Comment: I think there is a limit to the speed you can expect if you try to emulate explicit binary addition. Perhaps rather than bit arrays you can use byte arrays (thought of as a number in base 256) simulate adding 1 to those. 256 is not a huge number -- you can predefine a public array whose ith enthry is the base 2 expansion of i (padded with 0s if need be) so that e.g. you could just lookup 125 corresponds to "01111101" (perhaps it could even be an array of arrays where entry 125 has value Array(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1) for quick access to the bits.